# Tag merge: amazon-web-services & amazon-aws

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I believe the tags `amazon-web-services` and `amazon-aws` should be merged.  `amazon-web-services` has more questions, currently.  AWS stands for "Amazon Web Services", so they're both the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)